# How to get Gnome3's "Vino" (VNC Server) to start on login

Tags: gnome, vnc

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for several days and have not found anything that works as I want it to.

I'm looking for a way to start a VNC server that pulls from what is on the monitor (what my users see) and is available any time that a user is logged in (or all the time). I tested "RealVNC" and it works exactly as I would like, however I am in need of something that is opensource or at least more affordable for my organization.

I have tried multiple methods to run a VNC server as a service, and my only successes were opening a new display, where viewing the current Xorg session (Display :0) was not working. This method of using VNC as a terminal server is not quite what I am looking for.

It appears that Gnome3 includes a VNC server called "Vino" that is able to be toggled in settings as "Screen Sharing", however this appears to need to be set on a per user basis and i'm dealing with systems with multiple users connecting with LDAP credentials so manually turning this on for all users in a no-go.

If there was a way that I could have the "Vino" application/service start on login/unlock, and shutdown on logout/lock that would work for my needs, however I havent had any luck finding a mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

The command to start the server is

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

Just place this command in whatever means your desktop uses to autostart things.

I use LXDE, so I place it in Preferences/Default Applications for LXSession/Autostart